# Formula for EXCEL - INDEX MATCH, LARGE and MULTIPLE CRITERIA

Tags: excel, indexing, match, criteria

[image]

Is there a function to INDEX, MATCH, based on the criteria that the select Fruit is "TRUE", based on how LARGE their sales number is?

I've tried AGGREGATE, and multiple solutions, but I cannot find one that effectively matches the LARGEST based on the criteria that it is true.

Appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: do you have the dynamic formula FILTER and SORT?

Comment: I haven't tried that!

Comment: Hi Scott, dynamic FILTER and SORT does not work out

Comment: It should. Please edit the post and describe how you used it.